My parents are getting a divorce how do I prevent it if I am the cause?
So I play a sport and I am a state player
for the past four years, I have always been on and off badminton while going through thick and thin with my sisters and family . Every time I do something wrong, my whole family gets scolded And I have to live with that thought that I’m the cause of everyone’s misery . My mother (especially)gets scolded for whether it’s not giving me proper nutrition or not enough sleep .my dad is very very ambitious and is very supportive but he gets worked up and hits people when things aren’t his way . My mom just absorbs the pain and takes all the negativity in .. My dad really wants me to be an Olympic Champion. I’m not saying I don’t want to be a champion.. I have the body the height and the money and support from my family … I am also trying my best . recently My dad hired a personal caretaker to take care of me to manage my badminton schedule and train me.. but recently the caretaker brought his family over from another state which angers my dad since he is putting less effort and less time so that he can spend more time with his family . I understand since my dad is paying him 500 per day for a month and he is spending around 3 hours a day only and his cost monthly is around 15,000 ( people in my country earn a average 3000-5000per month ) . And my dad thinks he is doing it for the money and it is good money but I can assure you that it is not for the money . Since he is pretty well off and has 4 successful sons . So yea , today my dad got angry again since he probably didn’t sleep well and had scolded my mom and me because I didn’t take a nap in the afternoon .. everytime he tells me to quit but I write him a letter and we just continue again it has been going on this cycle for forever and he is losing hope in me . I have started to change my attitude now but since he is spending thousands per month he expects even more so I don’t know what I should do . Also, I don’t want or quit badminton I do it because I don’t want his and my effort , his money , my sacrifices and everyones time to go to waste .
anyways now my dad wants to divorce my mom because she doesn’t take proper care of me .. which makes me the cause … what can I do to stop it ? I don’t want to live with this burden that I have to carry “ my parents divorced because of me “ how do I stop it ??

Your parents are adults, and their relationship and choices are not your fault or responsibility to manage. Your father is treating your whole family abusively, which you did not cause and cannot fix.   I acknowledge it's very hard to be a kid or teen in a home where parents aren't in harmony, but truly you shouldn't blame yourself for the poor behavior of people with far more life experience.

First bit of advice: No child causes their parents’ divorce. Ever. No matter what others may say. It’s a decision made by one or two adults.

I voted to close this question, as there is no answer. But please know this: when a parent is physically and/or (especially) emotionally abusive, it is almost always the case that the kids will feel they are to blame instead of putting the responsibility for terrible behavior squarely on the abuser. Hand in hand with that, the abused will have very low self-esteeme, and making decisions under those circumstances is more difficult. Please know you're suffering from the effects of abuse when you deserve absolutely none of it.
